# Python Requests Post request fails when connecting to a Kerberized Hadoop cluster with Livy

Tags: python-2.7, hadoop, authentication, kerberos, livy

I'm trying to connect to a kerberized hadoop cluster via Livy to execute Spark code. The requests call im making is as below.

```
kerberos_auth = HTTPKerberosAuth(mutual_authentication=REQUIRED, force_preemptive=True)
r = requests.post(host + '/sessions', data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers, auth=kerberos_auth)
```

This call fails with the following error

> GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Failed
>   to find any Kerberos credentails)

Any help here would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When running Hadoop service daemons in Hadoop in secure mode, Kerberos tickets are decrypted with a keytab and the service uses the keytab to  determine the credentials of the user coming into the cluster.  Without a keytab in place with the right service principal inside of it, you will get this error message.  Please refer to [Hadoop in Secure Mode](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SecureMode.html) for further details on setting up the keytab.